# Why doesn't pasting X flipped pose paste arm poses?

Tags: animation

I suspect the cause might be the naming conventions of the arms, but I'm not sure.  Here's a picture of the model and armature with names.
[image]

Comment: Naming of the bones is important for blender to understand how to mirror the pose, bones should have exactly the same name with **L**, **R**, **Left**, **Right** suffixes or prefixes to be able to mirror the poses correctly.